# how do you equal a str's length to a certain number/length of digits

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I was using the if not equal to code but I needed the equal to code specifically for lengths from some previous posts I have tried this code of len(pin(4)) however this somehow still doesn't work
thank you in advance

```
pay =input("card or cash")
if pay ==("card"):
   pin = str(input("enter your pin number"))
while True:
   if len(pin)!=4:
      str(input("not four digit try again"))
      if len(pin(4)):
           print("payment cleared") 
   else:
      print("payment cleared")
      break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, starting with the formatting. You may use [essentially any form of tabbing or spacing in python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces), but the convention and general best practice is to use 4 spaces.

Next, the line. `if pay ==("card"):` is unnecessarily confusing.
`if pay == "card":` is much clearer and functions identically.

The first big error you make is to ask for the pin outside of the loop. Since your `pin = str(input("enter your pin number"))` occurs outside of your `while True:` loop, your program will only accept input once, then will enter an infinite loop unless the else clause of `len(pin)!=4` occurs.

The line `str(input("not four digit try again"))` makes absolutely no sense. Here, you are accepting input in a line which you surely instead meant to use the print statement instead, and on top of that you are unneccessarily converting the value entered via input into a string. A simple `print("not four digits! try again.")` will suffice here.

The line `if len(pin(4)):` should throw an error if run, as there is no builtin called pin which you should be able to call with `pin(4)`. The correct syntax would be `if len(pin) == 4:`.

I made a couple changes in the code below besides those described above to help with usability. I first convert the value of pin to integer to check if the value is a number. I assume that it is not inappropriate to represent a value which must clearly be a number as an integer in your example, but if you really want it to be a string you could use regex to check if it is a number or not with the re module. Something like `if re.match('[0-9]{4}', pin):` would work in this case.

```
pay = input("card or cash")
if pay == "card":
    while True:
        try:
            pin = int(input("enter your pin number: "))
            if len(str(pin))!=4:
                print("not four digits! try again.")
            else:
                print("payment cleared")
                break
        except ValueError:
            print('not a valid number! try again.')
```

Comment: @mahnoor iqbal I posted the code at first, but to help you learn you should check out the other comments I just added. I'm glad I could help.